# Push an array data

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array data and i want to push that data like this : 
`new LatLng([ 'lat' => -8.3901371, 'lng' => 115.211049 ]),new LatLng([ 'lat' => -8.3901953, 'lng' => 115.2110649 ]),new LatLng([ 'lat' => -8.3902752, 'lng' => 115.2110648 ]),`

then i write code like this :

```
$paths=[];
foreach ($data as $value){
    $koord = "new LatLng([
        'lat' => $value->wilayah_lat,
        'lng' => $value->wilayah_lng
    ]),";
    array_push($paths, $koord);      
 }
```

then, i want to access $paths using `print_r($paths)`, i always get data like this :
`Array ( [0] => new LatLng([ 'lat' => -8.3901371, 'lng' => 115.211049 ]), [1] => new LatLng([ 'lat' => -8.3901953, 'lng' => 115.2110649 ]), [2] => new LatLng([ 'lat' => -8.3902752, 'lng' => 115.2110648 ]),`

my question is, how do i access that data array on variable `$paths` look like that i want above ?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?? working fine for me.

Comment: so you'd like it to be as it will look like a string?

Comment: @ris i want to access array `$paths` as string, like this `new LatLng([ 'lat' => -8.3901371, 'lng' => 115.211049 ]),new LatLng([ 'lat' => -8.3901953, 'lng' => 115.2110649 ]),new LatLng([ 'lat' => -8.3902752, 'lng' => 115.2110648 ]),`

Comment: after array_push you can use impload function .

Comment: If you want to store data as one complete string then why do you need the array functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its still in array form, thats why when you `print_r` it, it still has its numeric index like the one shown. Either you `implode` the final array:

```
foreach ($data as $value){
    $koord = "new LatLng([
        'lat' => $value->wilayah_lat,
        'lng' => $value->wilayah_lng
    ])";
    $paths[] = $koord;      
}

$paths = implode(', ', $paths);
echo $paths;
```

Or make/initialize `$paths` as strings, then continually append/concatenate the rest of the strings in the loop:

```
$paths = '';
foreach ($data as $value){
    $paths .= "new LatLng([
        'lat' => $value->wilayah_lat,
        'lng' => $value->wilayah_lng
    ]),";     
}

$paths = rtrim($paths, ','); // remove excess/last comma
echo $paths;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Array store data with keys. SO your array look like `Array ([0] =>
>   'value ,...)`

If you want plain string use this code

```
implode(',',$array);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `implode` for this

```
 $paths=[];
    foreach ($data as $value){
        $koord = "new LatLng([
            'lat' => $value->wilayah_lat,
            'lng' => $value->wilayah_lng
        ])";                                    // remove the , from here .
        array_push($paths, $koord);      
     }

    echo implode(',',$paths);
```

Comment: `impload` should be `implode`

Answer (score -1):

To get **effect** like you want, retrieve data from array like this:

```
foreach($paths as $path){

    echo $path; 

}
```

**$paths** is the array from which you want to retrieve data.